# Reiniciar bucle para que me vuelva a preguntar al insertar un valor

Tags: shell-script

Estoy haciendo el siguiente código:

**SOLUCIÓN:**

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ $A <> 99 ]
echo "Escribe un valor"
read A
do
 if [ $A -ne 99 ]
      then
            echo "El cuadrado de $A es cuadrado=`expr $A \* $A`"
      else
            echo "Error"
            exit
      fi
done
```

Se puede observar que quiero tener un bucle que me pregunte por el valor que quiero introducir mientras que el número sea distinto a 99, es decir, cuando sea 99 mostrará el error y sale, esto lo hace bien.

El problema es que el bucle me realiza todo el rato a su vez el cuadrado del número,sin parar, la idea es que lo saque una vez y si ese número es distitnto a 99 entonces que me vuelva a preguntar por otro número y así sacando de nuevo su cuadrado, espero que me podáis ayudar.

Comment: ¿El `read A` no debería ir dentro del bucle?

Comment: Justo xd, he cambiado tantas veces el código que se me ha ido lo más básico, muchas gracias.